# How to skip headline in csv data when reading from StreamReader?

Tags: c#, csv

EDITED:

I have following code:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var date = new List<String>();
    var value = new List<Double>();

    string dir = @"C:\Main\test.csv";

    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dir))
    {
         var lines = File.ReadLines(dir)
                        .Skip(1);//Ignore the first line

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var fields = line.Split(new Char[] { ';' },   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                date.Add(fields[0]);
                if (fields.Length > 1)
                    value.Add(Convert.ToDouble(fields[1]));
            }


    String[] _date = date.ToArray();
    Double[] _value = value.ToArray();


    chart1.Series["Test"].Points.DataBindXY(_date,_value);
    chart1.Series["Test"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
  }
}
```

Now I want to skip the headline of the csv data. That means the first row of the first column and the first row of the second column. How to do that?

The headlines are Strings.When no headlines are in, he will skip the first row but with headlines I get a System.FormatException.

It fails when the first row contains Date in the first column and Value in the second column like that (opened with texteditor):

> "Date";"Value"
>
> "20.04.2010";"82.6619508214314"
>
> "21.04.2010";"33.2262968571519"
>
> "22.04.2010";"25.0174973120814"

Comment: _"That means the first row of the first column and the first row of the second column."_ So the first row ;)

Comment: Before your while loop just add `reader.ReadLine()`

Answer (score 6):

Why not just start by reading one line, and doing nothing with it?

```
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dir))
{
    reader.ReadLine(); // skip first

    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Why he doesn't want to skip the line when there are Strings in it (problem should be with the second column because it gets converted to double) - otherwise it will work

Comment: @uzi42tmp: Can you show a sample document in your post that fails?

Comment: first row - first column is Date and first row second column is Value

Comment: @uzi42tmp: Okay, they are quoted. Then do `fields[0].Trim('\"')` and `fields[1].Trim('\"')`.

Comment: I can try that tomorrow then I answer

Comment: @uzi42tmp: Glad it worked. Since you are new, please don't forget to accept the answer you liked best.

Answer (score 1):

Add one reader.ReadLine() before doing the while loop

```
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dir))
{
    if (reader.ReadLine()) //read first line
    {
     string line;
     while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) //read following lines
     {
     }
    }
}
```